# Python: Validate Regex, find a match inside string

Tags: python, django, regex

We have an invoice numbering rule, which we would like to modify a bit.

Inside user settings, there's a setting that sets the user invoice numbering format, we can let the user to change there anything he wants, but we have an invoice creation page, inside the page what we only want to allow is to let the user to change the number to a bit higher.

For example:

Inside settings the rule is set to `CN-002/2021`. Inside the invoice creation page the user tries to change the rule to `CN-001/2021`, in this case we will throw an error because we won't like to allow this. If the user tries to change the rule to `CN-003/2021`, we allow it.

NOTE: The user can't change anything else, for example, `CZ-003/2021` or `CN-001/2022`.

- Check if the number has changed:  `if old_invoice_no != new_invoice_no`
- Find which number has changed, for example, the old number was `CN-001/2021` and the new number is `CN-002/2021`. For this case, we will pass, because we only allow the number to be HIGHER and never LOWER. If the new number is `CN-000/2021` we will throw an error, because the number is lower.

How can I check if the number is not lower?

This is the whole code:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    old_invoice_no = instance.number # Output CN-002/2021
    new_invoice_no = validated_data.get("number") # CN-001/2021

    if old_invoice_no != new_invoice_no:
        # .. Now the number has changed, how can we find the new number which was changed?
        # The number which has changed is 001 to 002

        # If the number format didn't match we throw an error
        return ValidationError("msg_error_malformed_invoice_number_pattern")

    # Everything seems good, we can update the instance
    validated_data = self._update_validated_data(validated_data)
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    self._update_customer(validated_data, instance)
    return instance
```

Comment: What number should not be lower? The part before the `/` ? Thereafter? Is `CZ-003/2021` considered higher then e.g. `CN-002/2022` or lower (because of the year).

Comment: the part which can't be lower is before the `/`

Comment: NOTE: The user can't change anything else, for example, CZ-003/2021 or CN-001/2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```
import re

def validate(old, new):
    ost, omid, oend = re.split("[-/]", old)
    nst, nmid, nend = re.split("[-/]", new)
    if ost != nst or oend != nend:
        return False
    elif int(nmid) < int(omid):
        return False
    else:
        return True 

x = "CN-001/2021"
y = "CN-000/2021"
print(validate(x, y))
# False

x = "CN-001/2021"
y = "CN-002/2021"
print(validate(x, y))
# True
```

Here, we split the string at both `-` and `/`,so `"CN-001/2021"` becomes `["CN", "001", "2021"]`. I called the variable names start, middle, and end here (`ost` for "old start", `omid` for "old mid", etc...). This code then returns `False` if the customer has entered an invalid entry, and `True` if their input is valid.

I would suggest validating the middle number further. For example, you could ensure that:

1. `nmid` has the same number of characters as `omid`
2. `nmid` is composed entirely of digits

You also may want to return a message from the `validate` function to report back what actually went wrong with the validation (eg. "It is illegal to change the start of the invoice number").

You might also consider correcting some changes. For example, if the user tries to modify `"CN"` to become `"CZ"` but the input is otherwise valid, you might want to just accept their changes, but replace `nst` with `ost`. Going further, I would suggest not even allowing the user to enter the start and end portions of the invoice number and instead, just ask them to enter a new number `num` and then creating the new invoice number as `f"{ost}-{num}/{oend}"`

Comment: amazing answer, everything works. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the number is higher or lower by doing `str.split()` a couple of times if the format of your invoice number doesn't change...

### so your code can be modified as this in python3

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    old_invoice_no = instance.number # Output CN-002/2021
    new_invoice_no = validated_data.get("number") # CN-001/2021

    if old_invoice_no != new_invoice_no:
        if(int((new_invoice_no.split('/')[0]).split('-')[1]) < int((old_invoice_no.split('/')[0]).split('-')[1]) or (new_invoice_no.split('/')[0]).split('-')[0] != (old_invoice_no.split('/')[0]).split('-')[0] or new_invoice_no.split('/')[1] != old_invoice_no.split('/')[1]):
          # New number invalid
          return ValidationError("msg_error_malformed_invoice_number_pattern")

    # Everything seems good, we can update the instance
    validated_data = self._update_validated_data(validated_data)
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    self._update_customer(validated_data, instance)
    return instance
```

if you are using earlier versions of python then you need to use `string.atoi()` instead of the `int()` cast inside the `if`.
also the above only checks for what you specifically asked. This splits the string the same way multiple times but assuming the changes are not quite often. Should not be a bottleneck in your application.